# The type or namespace name 'OpenIdConnect' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Owin.Security' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, openid-connect

I have added a `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.dll` externally(tried both methods using Package Manager Console and using add reference ) to my ASP.NET MVC Application, but still get the same error.

> The type or namespace name 'OpenIdConnect' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Owin.Security' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I have attached `AccountController.cs`, `packages.config` and references

Any help.

[image: References]

[image: Acccount Controller][image: package confiq]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from Microsoft site 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/0e92xd7b(v=vs.110)

Possible causes for this error include the following:

- An assembly that contains the definition of a type was not referenced in the compilation; use /reference (Import Metadata) to specify the assembly
- You passed a variable name to the `typeof` operator.
- You tried to reference an assembly that is not part of your target .NET Framework profile. For more information, see Troubleshooting .NET Framework Targeting Errors.

In my case, the issue is that an assembly that is not part of my target .NET Framework profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with deleting Package folder from source directory (Location: .sln file), then try to resotre packages.

Steps to restore nuget packages:

1. Right click on solution file.
2. Select Nuget **restore NuGet Package option**

[image]